# Polymer 2 seeing app directory for elements?

Tags: polymer, web-component

When I use `polymer init` to create a polymer 2 element, I see that an /app directory is created. Is this expected? I'm being told by my team members that there should be no /app directory installed when creating a polymer 2 element.

I used `npm install -g polymer-cli@next` for the install. Also tried uninstalling and reinstalling again.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [this is not an expected behaviour](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli#element-project-layout).
This is not also a behaviour of the old version of the `polymer-cli`.

Can you please show your prompt result after running the command?

Comment: After creating a polymer 2 element using polymer init, I see it says 'setup complete' and now see the following directories created:
app, demo, test

Comment: Make sure you have installed the correct version of the `polymer-cli`. The latest one should be the `0.18.0`.  `npm install -g polymer-cli@0.18.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue was related to having a .bowerrc file in a parent directory. In there, the 'app' directory was specified. I simply had to remove the 'app' reference and when I ran `bower install` again bower_components were installed without the app directory.